# Re Write Infinite summation

Tags: summation, infinity

I want to re write the following summation: 
$$ \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_n(n+1)nx^{n-1}$$
I want to give it a form in terms of $x^{n+1}$, is this possible?

Comment: We have $\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_n(n+1)nx^{n-1}=x^{-2}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_n(n+1)n\:x^{n+1}$

Comment: @OlivierOloa Oh. I thought you had written $x^2$ instead of $x^{-2}$. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 
$$(n+1)nx^{n-1} = \frac{d}{dx}(n+1)x^n = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}x^{n+1}$$
we can rewrite the original sum as
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \frac{d^2}{dx^2}x^{n+1} = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^{n+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

We could shift the index $n$ to start from $n=-2$.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=-2}^\infty a_{n+2}(n+3)(n+2)x^{n+1}
> \end{align*}